# Thermal expansion of a rotating object

Tags: thermodynamics

I am having a discussion on the thermal expansion of a rotor in a supercharger.

The rotor is an alloy—I think it is 7000 series—and is held by a steel shaft.
The rotor is 152 mm long, and if I apply the basic thermal expansion equation to it, I find that it grows by 0.203130 mm if I increase the temperature by 60°C.
This rotor weighs 1835 g, is spinning at 20,000 RPM, and has a diameter of 105 mm.

If the heat is a constant, does the spinning effect have any influence on the thermal expansion, and—if so—is there math to work this out?

Cheers,
Baz

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. By "If the heat was a constant," do you mean that the temperature increase is fixed at 60°C? Why would the spinning then affect the thermal expansion? From centrifugal force?

Comment: Yes for the theory I am starting at 25deg C and then adding 60 deg C to the material.

In reality the temperature changes constantly, but I am more looking at if the speed of the rotor affects the thermal expansion if the temps were to remain a constant?

Comment: Again, why would the speed affect the thermal expansion?

Comment: I am not sure, I do not think it does, but I am not the best when it comes to physics, so I thought I would ask.
I was having a discussion about expansion and the other party seems to think that total expansion needs to have the force of rotation and pressure taken in to account to get the total expansion of the alloy..
I would have thought that the expansion of a solid would only be effected by the heat and the rate of rotation would have nothing at all to do with it....

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two effects that would make the rotor longer: thermal expansion and centrifugal stretching. Since both effects are small, it's probably safe to superpose them.

You're already calculated the thermal expansion (for a certain uniform temperature increase and temperature-independent thermal expansion coefficient). In addition to this expansion, the expansion from centrifugal stretching can be found analytically through integration or numerically through finite-element modeling, for example.

Going down the analytical road, any infinitesimal radial (radial meaning moving outward from the pivot or shaft, sorry if this is obvious) segment of the rotor is subjected to a [radial stretching force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) $$\omega^2r\,dm,$$ where $\omega$ is the angular speed, $r$ is the radial distance, and $dm$ is the infinitesimal mass. The force arises from any point on the rotor needing to accelerate the rest of the rotor to continue rotating rather than to fly off tangentially.

Assume that the cross section is uniform. By relating the mass to the volume and density, we could also express this force as  $$A\rho\omega^2r\,dr,$$ where $A$ is the cross-sectional area and $\rho$ is the density. The normal stress (force per unit area) is therefore $\rho\omega^2r\,dr$, and the tensile strain $\varepsilon$, assuming linear elasticity, is $\varepsilon=\rho\omega^2r\,dr/E$, where $E$ is the effective Young's modulus. This is multiplied by $r$, the portion of the rod that this strain applies to, to give $\rho\omega^2r^2dr/E$. This term can be integrated from $r=0$ to $r=R$, where $R$ is the rotor length, to give the total centrifugal-acceleration-related or spinning-related elongation of $$\frac{\rho\omega^2R^3}{3E},$$
corresponding to an elongation of approximately 0.005 mm.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, although I think it will take me some time to be able to work all of that out!!!!!